# Why would South Koreans grow cabbages at high altitudes?

Tags: cabbage

I happened upon this picture on p. 170 of [*National Geographic Night Vision: Magical Photographs of Life After Dark*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/34136384-national-geographic-night-vision) . The caption is on p 169.

[image]

[image]

1. Can anyone deduce the type of clouds, and thus the approximate
   altitude?
2. Most of South Korea is under 400 m. Why not grow cabbages at lower altitudes? Indubitably, high altitude gardening is more difficult.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this tour guide, ["Anbandegi The most beautiful cabbage patch made by hands."](http://www.gangneungtours.com/anbandegi.html#), the cabbage field is located above 1100 m on the mountainside.

They seem to have an answer to the other part of your question as well:

> After the Korean War, the people had come into the deep mountains, planted fields, and built a place to survive.

The area around Gangneung is surrounded by mountains so there were no real option for lower altitude farming. The cabbage fields cover 2 million square meters.

Comment: Cabbages also like and tolerate colder temperatures than many other crops; this could be one reason that they plant cabbages rather than, say, melons, at that altitude.